# Gmail filter with regular expressions

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I use **Gmail** and I'm receiving lots of emails I want to **filter**. They all have in common that the `subject` is like these:

```
Some words - r1234 - Some more words
Some words - r987665 - Some more words
Some words - r01 - Some more words
```

So, all of them have something like `- r... -` in the subject...

Is there any way to filter all those messages?

Comment: Ah, do "Some words" and "Some more words" vary each time? In that case my suggestion wouldn't work. I perhaps wrongly assumed that these two phrases were consistent among these emails? (Also, just realised that gmail doesn't seem to like searching for part words, so "wor" wouldn't find "word"!)

Answer (score 23):

[Googles help article 7190](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190) lists the search operators you can use in Gmail.
This article lists the AROUND keyword mentioned by [RADA](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/206271/rada).

Currently, using the `*` (SHIFT 8) also works. I use it as `*`=AnyTextHere.

e.g. "`Ticket* for user`" find `Ticket 1 for user` and `Ticket 2 for user` and `Ticket 1000 for user`.

Comment: This not working for me in `to` search eg to:(some_id*@some.email)

Comment: The original question was about filtering on the subject line. You are trying to filter on the `to:` field. Using `to:*@some.email` or `to:@some.email` works. Your request to use `to:string*@some.email` does not. Maybe Google uses `To` & `From` fields differently than the `Subject`?

Comment: Thanks for clear explain @IanC. Using AROUND works nicely now.

Answer (score 7):

For Gmail filtering you first need to construct the "Search Operators."  Although it's not a regular expression, you can still achieve what you want.

Some words - r1234 - Some more words

Would be something like "Some words AROUND 1 Some more words"

> Find messages with words near each other. Use the number to say how
>   many words apart the words can be

**AROUND**

Example: **holiday AROUND 10 vacation**

> Add quotes to find messages in which the word you put first stays
>   first.

Example: "secret AROUND 25 birthday"

Here is the [official help](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en)

I ended up here because I was trying to reduce the number of separate filters I had and wanted to group them together.  After reading the reference my messages are all clean.

from:("Twitter" OR "Facebook")

Answer (score 6):

## Short answer

Gmail doesn't include search features such wildcards or regular expressions.

## Alternatives

Use the Gmail API, Google Apps Script or third party application that include search features like wildcards or regular expressions.

## References

[Search in Gmail - Gmail Help](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6593?hl=en)

Comment: For an example Google Apps Script, see: https://github.com/paoloantinori/gmail-labeler After you filter out these emails, you can use the script to mark them as read or move them to your spam folder.

Comment: Gmail API doesn't support anything much more than the regular Gmail UI.

Answer (score 6):

Filtering "From" with:

```
*@someemail.com OR *@someothermail.com
```

Works for me.

Comment: Question is about doing it with regular expression on subjects.

Answer (score 4):

With this syntax, I was able to filter the right items. `[*]`

Real Life Example that I experienced.

```
marketing.2232322276.3231244.0@informationservices.hsbc.com.ph
marketing.2667489935.2768504.0@informationservices.hsbc.com.ph
marketing.2666668490.7685749.0@informationservices.hsbc.com.ph
```

So basically, their template is `marketing`[*generated number*]`@informationservices.hsbc.com.ph`

In order for me to filter it out, I did `marketing[*]@informationservices.hsbc.com.ph`

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with google's AROUND keyword.

For example, I have a filter set up to delete emails with the subject line like *"Your December 2018 Transaction History"*. To match any change in dates, I've set the subject to *"Your AROUND Transaction History"*. It works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script), you can use this function to filter email threads by a given regex:

```
function processInboxEmailSubjects() {
  var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads();
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    var subject = threads[i].getFirstMessageSubject();
    const regex = /- r\d.* -/; //change this to whatever regex you want, this one should cover OP's scenario
    let isAtLeast40 = regex.test(subject)
    if (isAtLeast40) {
      Logger.log(subject);

      // Now do what you want to do with the email thread. For example, skip inbox and add an already existing label, like so:
      threads[i].moveToArchive().addLabel("customLabel")
    }
  }
}
```

As far as I know, unfortunately there isn't a way to trigger this with every new incoming email, so you have to create a time trigger like so:

```
function createTrigger(){ //you only need to run this once, then the trigger executes the function every hour in perpetuity
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('processInboxEmailSubjects').timeBased().everyHours(1).create();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I haven't tried regex, but the current help doc specifies (with examples) the operators you can use to filter search results.

https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en

Answer (score -3):

I just want to update this post since it has incorrect (or outdated ) information.  Gmail **does support** wildcards.  I have the following  wildcard set up for subject  *Privacy Policy*  ...and it works great.  I **don't** want those words to apply to body since it can be at the bottom of most emails.

Like so: `* Privacy Policy *`.

Comment: I think you'll find that `"subject:privacy policy"` works just as well. It's still not wildcard support.

Comment: Just to clarify, I'm talking about setting filters not searching.  But you are right about not needing the *.   I just added Privacy Policy and it found it even when they were NOT the first words in the subject.  I could swear it would not work the first time I tried it.  Maybe it took a minute to update.   Also so people do not get confused, GMAIL adds "subject:" on its own when using the setup screen.